# Sphinx search tricks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have some questions regarding sphinx search and thinking sphinx gem

- Is it possible to find similar results for record? For example - similar posts for current post in blog application?
- If my app is indexing different models (for example in blog app - posts, comments and pages) is it possible to perform search on every model with one request, but not performing search in every model (Post.search 'string', Comment.search 'string' etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Dont know about part 1 of your question, but i'm sure you can do the second i.e. Search across multiple models.

Here's the reference

```
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#global
```

Comment: Aditya deserves the credit, as he's answered the second question. As for the first - no, Sphinx cannot do that. For what it's worth, I don't think that's a **search** problem, but a **comparison** problem. A search engine isn't the right tool for that job.